# ¿Cómo puedo implementar un algoritmo en JavasScript para resolver un sliding puzzle 4x3 numérico el cual tiene 3 espacios vacíos?

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto, inteligencia-artificial, game

Necesito implementar un algoritmo en JavasScript que resuelva un sliding puzzle 4x3 numérico el cual tiene 3 espacios vacíos.

Ejemplo: Desde la situación inicial llegar a la situación final

[image: sliding puzzle 4x3 con 3 espacios vacíos]

Entiendo que al haber múltiples espacios vacíos siempre tiene que poderse encontrar una solución, por lo que no debería contemplar la situación de que no pueda resolverse. Vi que existen varios métodos, por ejemplo, A*, pero no se como adaptarlo a la situación particular de tener varios espacios vacíos, ya que tomando la estrategia de mover los espacios vacíos en vez de los números, debería recorrer las ramas generadas por cada uno de los 3 espacios vacíos, lo cual resulta bastante complejo de modelar.

Se acepta para la solución representar los datos como arrays u objetos indistintamente, en lo posible sin utilizar bibliotecas de terceros, es decir, vanilla js.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a S.O. Español, Por favor compartenos el código de lo que has intentado, [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Me siento como recibiendo una lista de requerimientos en el trabajo, pero sin que me paguen.

Comment: Pronto subiré el código que tengo avanzado a modo demostrativo. Se me acaba de ocurrir una solución parcial: asignar un valor a dos de los espacios vacios (ejemplo: 10 y 11) y luego resolver con A* como si fuese un 4x3 tradicional de un solo espacio vacio. Limitaciones: puede que tarde mas tiempo en resolver y solo aplicable a 4x3 tradicionales que tengan solución